# What's the name/slang for off screen dialogue added in post for clarification purposes?

Tags: adr, voice-over, dubbing

I forget exactly where I heard it, but there is a term (could be slang) for off screen dialogue added in post procuction to help clarify scenes or to add additional off screen characters.  I can't remember for the life of me.  I want to say it's called a "slug", but I'm certain that's something else.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you thinking of stingers??

Comment: I know exactly what you're referring to. I'm certain I read about this term in a book not too long ago. I'm in the process of going through those and once I find it I'll of course post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's ADR (additional/automated dialogue replacement)
Wildtracks, buzz track. In the states you often hear the term 'walla' to describe crown muttering or bg chatter of any kind. 
slug usually means a short section of sound often silence

Answer (score 1):

"Loop Group" is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

We use 'add lines' to describe anything that was added in post.  Walla is used to describe anything in the background.  Before we have the script for the 'add' lines we refer to them as TBW's (to be written).  That way we know which lines in our ADR list need to be addressed.

Answer (score -1):

Post sync or post synchro here in Europe. ;)

Answer (score -1):

"Wala?" Describes background dialogue that is intentionally meaningless and unintelligible.